# I am unable to read EAST: An Efficient and Accurate Scene Text Detector as .pb file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, object-detection

I am working on extracting text from an Image (OCR) and it should display the text on boundary box using EAST. As EAST is .PB file and I am working on Jupyter notebook. I am unable to read the file. `[net = cv2.dnn.readNet(args["east"]` results in error: `OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:3780: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Cannot determine an origin framework of files: C:/Python/resnet_v1_50.ckpt in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20190122::readNet)`. Can someone help in solving the issue.

I have tried opening/converting the .pb file to other fromats using software such as Fantaisie Software, but they are paid ones, so i have failed. Are there any free softwares to read the model. Also i am unable to open two layers `layerNames = ["feature_fusion/Conv_7/Sigmoid","feature_fusion/concat_3"]`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import pytesseract
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

args = {"image":"C:/Users/temp/Desktop/download.jpg", "east":"C:/Python/resnet_v1_50.ckpt", "min_confidence":0.5, "width":320, "height":320}

args['image']="C:/Users/temp/Desktop/Cheque.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(args['image'])

orig = image.copy()
(origH, origW) = image.shape[:2]

(newW, newH) = (args["width"], args["height"])

rW = origW / float(newW)
rH = origH / float(newH)

image = cv2.resize(image, (newW, newH))
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0, (W, H),(123.68, 116.78, 103.94), swapRB=True, crop=False)

net = cv2.dnn.readNet(args["east"])

layerNames = ["feature_fusion/Conv_7/Sigmoid","feature_fusion/concat_3"]

net.setInput(blob)
(scores, geometry) = net.forward(layerNames)
```

soooooo...onnnnn

Unable to load, and run the model

Answer (score 0):

1. You should load your dnn file from this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/).
2. Extract your 'frozen_east_text_detection.pb' file to desktop.
3. You need to change your code like this:

   ```
   net = cv2.dnn.readNet('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\frozen_east_text_detection.pb')
   ```

It's going to load successfully.

**EDIT**: These errors occurs because of inability to file read.

```
    cv::dnn::dnn4_v20190122::readNet
```